# Running Batch python processes on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have couple of Python scripts which I would like to schedule to run once a month on Google cloud. The scripts basically trigger DLP jobs, extract data catalog information to a file in GCS. These batch workloads would hardly run for 30 mins. And so I don't need to use services like GKE, composer etc which are very resource intensive.

For these batch workloads I would like to know the best options available in GCP. Looking at some of the blog posts I found below article to use Cloud Scheduler-> Pub/Sub-> Cloud Functions -> Create VM (using a startup script).
https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-a-serverless-batch-workload-on-gcp-with-cloud-scheduler-cloud-functions-and-compute-86c2bd573f25

I have below questions with above design..
1) How long does the Cloud Function run as it starts the VM? I know cloud function has a timeout of 9mins ..what happens if the VM takes longer than 9mins to process the startup script?

Any other design ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can start a VM instance asynchronously. Your function does not need to wait for the VM to run.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of that medium post.

1) How long does the Cloud Function run as it starts the VM?
You can change the Cloud Function code to not wait for the response, It's using NodeJS so you just don't have to wait for the Promise.
Also in that solution the Cloud Function job is only to trigger the VM creation.

```
  .createVM(vmName, vmConfig)
  .then(data => {
    // Operation pending.
    const vm = data[0];
    const operation = data[1];
    console.log(`VM being created: ${vm.id}`);
    console.log(`Operation info: ${operation.id}`);
    return operation.promise();
    // This will return right away with the VM pending state, you can finish 
    // your logic here, and not wait for VM creation to finish.
    // You can even ignore this step if you don't need the VM ID logged for 
    // debugging purposes
  })
  .then(() => {
    const message = 'VM created with success, Cloud Function finished execution.';
    console.log(message);
  }
```

Using that same code, in the worst case (if it takes more than 9 minutes), the Cloud Function will timeout but the VM creation will continue.

Answer (score 0):

The desing that I suggest is using: Cloud Scheduler + Pub/Sub + Compute Engine

This design in few words:
- you compute engine will have a utility that listens to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic
- this utility will execute upon receiving a new event from the Topic and run a cron job on the instance
- Cloud scheduler is used here to push messages to the Pub/Sub Topic in a time that you can specify in your job.

> By using Pub/Sub to decouple the task-scheduling logic from the logic
>   running the commands on Compute Engine, you can update your cron
>   scripts as needed, without updating the Cloud Scheduler configuration.
>   You can also change your task schedule without updating the utility
>   service on your Compute Engine instances

you can find full explanation of this design and a sample code by following [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine) and [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample).

let me know if there is anything not obvious.

Comment: Methkal..the idea was to on the fly spinup a Compute VM, execute the startup script and delete the VM ...with your design I guess the compute needs to be running to listen to pub/sub event for running the cron job...is that right?

Comment: hey @John , indeed you will need an instance to that cron job. you can use [preemptible instances](https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms) or just create a script that remove this instance after it finishes its work.